# execute a command before a parameters processing

Tags: powershell, parameters

I wrote script just like below, but AD PowerShell module is necessary, that I maked a function which checking command and installing AD feature.
But I need do that before executing of parameters, if I putting my function before "param" that i getting an error. Someone know how can I execute a command/function before parameters processing?

Script code:

```
Param(
    $user="user",
    $hosts = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'ou=temp,dc=lab,dc=test,dc=com').Name,
    $credential = (Get-Credential -Message "Type user/pass  ")
)
Copy-Item -Path "path" -Destination "dest"
```

Function code:

```
function GET-mandatory-modules {
    Write-Host "checking availability of necessery modules" -ForegroundColor Green
    #ad module
    if (!(Get-Command Get-ADComputer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Host "GET-ad-computer command unavailable, installing module AD-powershell" -ForegroundColor yellow
        Get-WindowsFeature |
            where name -like RSAT-AD-PowerShell |
            Install-WindowsFeature
    } else {
        Write-Host "ad-module is avialable, installation is not necessery"
    }
} #end function GET-mandatory-modules
```

Error sample:

```
    $user="user",
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator
must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or
a property.
```

Comment: Typically you would use the [#Requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-6) statement to prevent your script running if a required module wasn't present.  For example: `#Requires -Modules ActiveDirectory`

Comment: I'ts good solution but , it's only informing that we doesn't have a required module and don't allowing  to run script , but id'like to automatic install requirements.

Comment: Installing Windows features is a (major, system-wide) side-effect of your script and not it's main purpose.  Personally, I'd consider it back practice to install/configure things just to get your code to work.  The system owner should be the one to do that, then they can call your code.  I know you may also be the system owner, but these two task should be kept separate - at least, there should be an `-InstallRequiredFeatures` parameter or similar, so the caller understands what might happen.

Comment: cont...  Having said that, you could wrap your current code in a function within the script, then have the main code check/install the feature, then call the function afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

A powershell script always starts with parameter processing. There is no way to avoid that. But I do not see the need to add the $hosts to the parameters of the script. It can be done like this:

```
param(
  $user="user",
  [PSCredential]$credential=(get-credential -message "Type user/pass  ")
)

Get-mandatory-modules
$hosts = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'ou=temp,dc=lab,dc=test,dc=com').Name
Copy-item -path "path" -destination "dest"
```

If you nevertheless want to be able to pass the organizational unit as a parameter you could do that as a string that is used in the script to get computer names:

```
param(
  $user="user",
  $hostsou = 'ou=temp,dc=lab,dc=test,dc=com'
  [PSCredential]$credential=(get-credential -message "Type user/pass  ")
)

Get-mandatory-modules
$hosts = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $hostsou).Name
Copy-item -path "path" -destination "dest"
```